# Count chains in complete graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pathfinding

Let's say I have a complete graph like this

```
W = {1, 2};
n = 5;
p2 = 0.5;
p1 = 1 - p2;
arr = {};
AppendTo[arr, RandomChoice[{p1, p2} -> {1, 2}, n]];
el1 = VertexList[CompleteGraph[n]];
g = CompleteGraph[n, 
  VertexLabels -> Table[el1[[i]] -> arr[[1]][[i]], {i, Length[el1]}], 
  VertexSize -> .10]
SeedRandom[1];
chain = {1,2,2};
```

There are 6 possible chains `{1,2,2}` for this particular graph [image]

I need to write a function that receives a complete graph `g` and a chain `chain`(`1 < Length[chain] < n`) and returns a number of such chains in `g`.

Comment: Look up "graph coloring"... a very well-developed field which uses colors instead of the labels 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you clarify, ideally through a concrete example, what you mean by "the number of required chains", or even what you mean by "chain" in this context?

Comment: is it always the case that  `Length[chain] <= VertexCount[g]`?

Comment: Yes, it is like that ```1 < Length[chain] < n```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"
> ```

```
ClearAll[chainCount]

chainCount[g_, p_] /; SubsetQ[Values@AnnotationValue[g, VertexLabels], p] := 
 Module[{cp = Counts @ p, 
   cg = Counts @ Values @ AnnotationValue[g, VertexLabels]}, 
  Apply[Times] @
   MapApply[FactorialPower] @
    Select[Length @ # == 2 &] @ Merge[Identity] @ {cg, cp}]

chainCount[g_, p_] = 0;
```

***Examples:***

```
n = 5;
p = 0.5;
SeedRandom[1];
arr = RandomChoice[{1 - p, p} -> {1, 2}, n];

g = CompleteGraph[n, VertexLabels -> {v_ :> arr[[v]]}, VertexSize -> .10]


chainCount[g, {1, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
chainCount[g, {1, 1, 2}]
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

```
chainCount[g, {2, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
chainCount[g, {1, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
chainCount[g, {1, 2, 1, 1}]
12
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but, for example, ```chainCount[g, {1, 2, 2}]``` returns ```<|2 -> {2, 2}, 1 -> {3, 1}|>```

Comment: @mclord, could be version/os difference (I am using v13.0 for linux x86). Try also starting with a fresh kernel.